# have to plug/un-plug usb devices on system booting?

Tags: usb

it's so weired that i have to plug/unplug in my usb devices every time booting ubuntu.
it happens for both installing ubuntu and booting ubuntu (10.10 and 11.10)

the scenario is like:

1.bios checking -> 
2.grub start -> 
3.keyboard & mouse led OFF (black screen with a cursor on top-left) ->
4.i plug/unplug in any usb devices ->
5.everything is back to normal and ubuntu started

it's really frustrating :( please advise the solution.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd> to get bios menu

then uncheck *boot usb first* option save the settings and restart